# Adding Named Range reference in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am trying to add a string to a named range's Refersto value. The issue is that the string has to being with a "=" to be used with another internal tool. I can create the string easily, but i get the error attached when I try to add the reference. Is there any way to override the error, and place the string having a "=" at the start of the string. A VERY simplified mocked up example is below:

```
Public Sub AddReference() 

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DG_PRINT_SETTINGS_001", RefersTo:="={""""001"""",""""print_settings""""}"

End Sub
```

Any help to make this work would be great as I can't change the other end of the process, I need to shoehorn this to work. I know its possible beacuse its done elsewhere, but the guy who wrote the code is no longer around and I can't ask him...I am kinda SOL

[image]

Comment: We do not see the error that you speak of.

Comment: There was an error with the syntax that I corrected, and verified that this sub, when run, gives me the error.  I am using Excel 2013, 64bit if that makes an ounce of difference

Comment: You still don't name the error in your question. You say it's "attached."

Comment: Can't you just assign a `Range` object reference to the `RefersTo` parameter?

Comment: @Mat'sMug no its a string that is pulled apart by another program I have no access to.  Hence the shoe horn comment.  Or are you saying instead of it being a string, make it a range object?

Comment: What value do you actually *need* in the `RefersTo`? I.e., when the other program reads this, what is it expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mind the string quotes `"`

This will work :

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="DG_PRINT_SETTINGS_002", RefersTo:="={""001"",""print_settings""}"
```

[image]

Comment: 64 0r 32 bit doesn't make any difference Why so many quotes. Dou want `"001"` or `""00""`.

Comment: I get errors and output I am not looking for with any fewer quotes

Comment: what errors? share the error message? Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes I get RTE 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @Darw1n34 that error can't possibly be raised from that line of code, unless `ActiveWorkbook` is `Nothing`. It's very likely something else throwing the error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug in my zealous speed, I realized I was still working in the .xla.  That RTE 91 is gone  but the original error still exists

Comment: @cyboashu It worked,  I must have had something in the workbook i wasn't seeing, because I tried it fresh and it worked.  Kudos!